# Add a max length property on an xml field?

Tags: xml

I have this xml and need to limit output to 140 characters

```
<Ustrd>
   <xsl:value-of select="Extend/Remit_Msg"/>
 </Ustrd>
```

Comment: I tried this, but my file is erroring out when it runs:                                                               <Ustrd>
 <xsl:value-of select="substring(/Extend/Remit_Msg,1,140)"/>
 </Ustrd>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that with the [`substring`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_substring.html) function:

```
<Ustrd>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(Extend/Remit_Msg,1,140)" />
</Ustrd>
```